# Is a set Anti-Symmetric if it's all reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Lets say I have a set of integers of $-7\ to \ 7$
And $ R = {(a,b)|a^3=b^3} $

I don't understand anti-symmetry fully and I'm wondering if a set is only reflexive then it must be anti-symmetric?

Also is it:
Reflexive?
Symmetric?
Anti-symmetric?
Transitive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if a relation consists of all and *only* ordered pairs relating each and element of the set with itself, then by definition it is reflexive, and it is *trivially* antisymmetric, symmetric, and transitive.

Your relation $R$, that is, consists of all and only those ordered pairs such that $\forall x$ in $S = \{-7, -6, \ldots 0, \ldots 6, 7\},\; (x, x)\in R$, with $(x, y) \notin R whenever $x, y \in S$ and x \neq y$.

Put differently, a reflexive set such as this is trivially antisymmetric, symmetric, and transitive because the relation *cannot fail* to be symmetric, cannot fail to be antisymmetric, and cannot fail to be transitive.

Recall the definitions of the properties of a relation, for example, symmetry: "Whenever it is the case that $x R y$...then...$y R x$". This allows us to *only* test pairs of elements that DO satisfy "$x R y ...$." In the case at hand, the only pairs that satisfy the relation are pairs of the form $(x, x)$. And given all and only such pairs,

- it is always true that for all $x$ in your set, $x R x$, since $x^3 = x^3$ for all $x\in S$ (reflexive).
- It is always true that IF $x R x$, then $x R x$ (symmetric)
- It is always true that IF $x R x$ and $x R x$, then $x = x$ (antisymmetric)
- It is always true that IF $x R x$ and $x R x$, then $x R x$ (transitive)

Some equivalence relations can be antisymmetric, as in this case.

Comment: It can't be Symmetric can it? Since $-7^3 \not= -6^3 $
And Symmetric: $ xRy \land yRx $

Comment: but $-7^3 \neq 6^3$, so $-7$ is not related to $6$. We only need for $x = y$ when it's the case that $x, y$ are related.  Your relation consists of only pairs $(x, x)$, i.e. $x R x, y R y$... and if $x \neq y$, then $x \not R y$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, would I apply the connections between the elements to the set with the relation. Then see if the symmetric properties are true or false for the connections applied?


Or would I apply the Symmetric properties to the set with relation specified?

Comment: Recall that a relation $R$ is symmetric if for all $x, y$ in the set, IF $x R y$ AND $y R x$ THEN $x = y$. For your relation, if $x\neq y$, then it is NOT the case that $x R y$ or $y R x$, so the IF part is false, and that's why it's trivially symmetric, because there are no such cases when $x \neq y$ so it doesn't matter that they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the squares, not cubes in your example. This equivalence relation is reflexive, but is't antisymmetric: $(-6)R(6) ~\&~ (6)R(-6)~ \& ~(-6 \ne 6  )$

Comment: That's not true for all equivalence relations: in equivalence relations which are essentially the relation of equality, antisymmetry and symmetry hold. Recall that antisymmetry is NOT the antonym of symmetry.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Edited.

Comment: The problem I'm working on involves cubes.

Comment: The cube function is here isomorphic, so if you relation is, a trivial relation on the set, which is got using such function, it gonna save all its properties. It was an equivalence, was reflexive and antisymmetric, so it still is.

Comment: $x^3 = y^3 \iff x = y$ does indeed satisfy symmetry. $(-6)^3 \neq 6^3$, so $(-6)\not R 6$

Comment: Why? Your comment is fully wrong, why do you change $=$ to $\ne$? It saves the properties of $\ne$ on $-7..7$, so as I said.

Comment: $-6 R 6$ IF AND ONLY IF $(-6)^3 = -216 = 6^3 = 216$ But clearly, $-216 \neq 216$. So $-6\not R 6$. A relation is antisymmetric IF AND ONLY IF it is the case that **IF $x R y$ AND $y R x$**, then x = y. When the **condition** isn't satisfied, it doesn't matter whether the equality is satisfied or not.

Comment: I'm commenting on your post's conclusion that the relation **isn't** antisymmetric, when it is.

Comment: I wrote about the squares.